# Unable to add date on x-axis in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a line graph with dates ranging 31 days from the current date. My y-axis is working and I'm sure I’m missing something while defining the x-axis. **The y-axis has values from -100 to 100 and the x-axis is supposed to have dates as defined.**

Here is the code

```
let parseDate = d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d');

    for (i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
        results[i] = parseDate(results[i]);
    }

    var min = results[0];
    var max = results[31];

    var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([min, max]).range([0, 100]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-200, 200]).range([100, 0]);

    var bezierLine = d3
        .line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d[0]);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d[1]);
        })
        .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
```

My `results` is of the format `2020-05-22`

Comment: If your `results` array contain dates, use it as it is. If it has strings, as it seems to be the case, you want to use `let parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d')` instead of `let parseDate = d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d')`. Finally, don't rely on the array's order, just use `domain(d3.extent(results))`.

Comment: Yes, my `results` is an array of strings. As soon as I use `timeFormat` instead of `timeParse` my `min` and `max` become null. I think thee issue is with how I'm defining `bezierLine`'s `x`

Comment: I told you t use `d3.timeParse`, not `d3.timeFormat`.

Comment: Yes, sorry...  I meant using `d3.timeParse` makes the `results` array `null`